# Why is the space of smooth sections complete?

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces, frechet-manifold

This page is about the  [space of sections](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/space+of+sections):

> Let $E \stackrel{\mathrm{fb}}{\rightarrow} \Sigma$ be a smooth vector bundle.  On its real vector space $\Gamma_{\Sigma}(E)$ of smooth sections consider the seminorms indexed by a compact subset $K \subset \Sigma$ and a natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ and given by
> $$
> \begin{aligned}
> \Gamma_{\Sigma}(E) & \stackrel{p_{K}^{N}}{\longrightarrow} [0,\infty)\\
> \Phi & \longmapsto \max _{n \leq N}\left(\sup _{x \in K}\left|\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{n} \Phi(x)\right|\right)
> \end{aligned}
> $$
> where on the right we have the absolute values of the covariant derivatives of $\Phi$ for any fixed choice of connection on $E$ and norm on the tensor product of vector bundles $\left(T^{*} \Sigma\right)^{\otimes_{\Sigma}^{n}} \otimes_{\Sigma} E$.

Let $(U, \varphi, \rho)$ be a total trivialization triple for $E$.and  $u \in \Gamma_{U}(E)$. On  $U$  we may write  $u=u^{a} s_{a}$

Now in general we have  $$\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} 
u=\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \ldots i_{1}}^{a} d x^{i_{1}} \otimes \cdots \otimes d x^{i_{k}} \otimes s_{a}$$

where $$\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}^{a} \circ \varphi^{-1}=\frac{\partial ^k}{\partial x^{i_{1}} \ldots \partial x^{i_{k}}}\left(u^{a} \circ \varphi^{-1}\right)+\sum_{\underline{n} \mid<k_{l}} \sum_{l=1} C_{\eta l} \partial^{\eta}\left(u^{l} \circ \varphi^{-1}\right)$$

where for each $\eta$ and $l, C_{\eta l}$ is a polynomial in terms of Christoffel symbols (of the linear connection on $M$ and connection in $E$ ).

Now suppose we have a metric $g$ in $U$ and a metric $h$ in $E$ then we have that
$$\left|\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{n} u\right|= \left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{i_{1} \cdots i_{k}}^{a}\left(\left(\nabla^{E}\right)^{k} u\right)_{j_{1} \cdots j_{k}}^{b} g^{i_1 j_i}\cdots g^{i_k j_k}h^{ab}$$
How to prove that this space is complete in respect to the seminorm?

Now In this  article on page 6 [GREEN-HYPERBOLIC OPERATORS ON GLOBALLY HYPERBOLIC SPACETIMES](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0738) the author says that an Arzelà-Ascoli argument would show this but I don't see how.

If anyone would like me to  expand the question please let me know.

Comment: Start with a Cauchy sequence, it is a Cauchy sequence wrt the zeroth derivative, so it converges locally uniformly. Next you apply the same argument for the first derivative and so on.

Comment: @Echo I can do that in the case of a flat connection but  I having problem to proof that in the case of general connection

Comment: Looking at the case of a trivial line bundle, would not you actually need a relaxed notion of "smooth"? You should obtain something like Sobolev spaces, no?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე I did not understand your comment

Comment: When $\Sigma$ is the real line, $E$ is a trivial line bundle and the connection is trivial, so that $\nabla^n$ is the usual $n$th derivative, you would get the space of smooth functions. In which sense is it complete? The only way to complete it I know is to extend to a [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space) which means adding some functions that are only smooth in a weak sense. Or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: Oh I see now I overlooked that you do not need Banach spaces, only Fréchet spaces, right?

Comment: @მამუკა ჯიბლაძე yes I need  the proof that the spaces of smooth sections is a  frechet space using this seminorm.

Comment: I know that the space of smooth section is a frechet topology  using the isomorphism between the local section and vector valued function and then using the projective topology,but I want to proof it with this seminorm and I have no Idea where to start

Comment: Start with a Cauchy sequence, as mentioned, it will converge locally uniformly. Take a compact set K over which the bundle becomes trivial. Using a trivialisation, you show that all derivatives converge on K. Do that for every such compact set.

Comment: @Echo When we introduce trivialization we will  have other derivatives plus other parts due to the connection. I am not understanding why you say that derivatives converges

Comment: These are linear combinations of the given ones, where the coefficients are smooth, hence locally bounded, functions.

Comment: @Echo I will try to do as you said and then edit my question in case of any doubt

Comment: The existence of a $C^0$ limit of a Cauchy sequence is straightforward. Assume you have a Cauchy sequence with respect to the $C^k$ norm,. Each $k$-th order covariant derivative of a section consists of $k$-order partial derivatives plus terms that contain lower order partial derivatives times partial derivatives of the Christoffel symbols. The latter terms converge to limits by induction. Now apply Arzela-Ascoli to the $k$-th order terms.

Comment: This question is really more appropriate for math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This should be really asked in math.stackexchange.com but for your convenience: here is a link to lecture notes https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706 of mine where you have a very detailed proof.